# WebView2 Navigate

Tags: webbrowser-control, webview2

I got an old Windows Forms Tool that I wrote a few years ago, which is using WebBrowser. I want to change it to WebView2 so it's more compatible with new Browsers, as it won't work anymore if you have like Edge Browser installed.

Here is my original Code which works:

```
public void SubmitData(string link = "")
{
    WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();

    try
    {
        if(link != "")
        {
            wb.Navigate(link, "_Blank");
        }
        else
        {
            String postdata = "portfolio=" + ControlHelper.SerializeXMLString(pf);
            System.Text.Encoding encod = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            byte[] bytVal = encod.GetBytes(postdata); 
            
            //navString = "http://lt.morningstar.com/4uzvsjb3c3/xray/default.aspx?" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(bytVal);

            wb.Navigate("http://lt.morningstar.com/4uzvsjb3c3/xray/default.aspx", "_Blank", bytVal, "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");                    
        }                                
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        FileLogger.HandleError("Submit caused an error!", true, true, "Error (Main, SubmitData): " + ex.Message, GlobalData._TempPath, GlobalData._logfile);
    }
    finally
    {
        //use to close app and dispose
        wb.Dispose();               
    }
}
```

This is the new one, on which I get an error: ("The object reference was not set to an object instance.")

```
WebView2 wb2 = new WebView2();

String postdata = "portfolio=" + ControlHelper.SerializeXMLString(pf);
System.Text.Encoding encod = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
byte[] bytVal = encod.GetBytes(postdata);

navString = "http://lt.morningstar.com/4uzvsjb3c3/xray/default.aspx?" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(bytVal);
Uri uri = new Uri(navString);

wb2.CoreWebView2.Navigate(navString);
            
//wb2.Source = uri;
wb2.Show();
```

I haven't worked with this for quite a while, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.
I appreciate any help on this.

Comment: It looks like you're using the CoreWebView2 property before waiting for it to be initialized. You need to `await wb2.EnsureCoreWebView2Async();`